# Is there a package for tracking local history of files like in IntelliJ or Eclipse?

Tags: version-control

*Local History* is a feature in IntelliJ and Eclipse, which for every file keeps a history of its changes:

- [IntelliJ Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/local-history.html)
- [Eclipse Local History](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-55.htm)

It is not a replacement for revision control systems like Git, but I found it useful when experimenting with code.

Is there a way in Emacs to allow browsing through changes in one file and being able to select one version and revert to it?

Comment: https://github.com/pidu/git-timemachine

Comment: See ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-20-2.5/html_chapter/elisp_toc.html#TOC397 to make numbered backups (with some more configuration you can get something similar to Eclipse's local history).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [undo-tree](https://melpa.org/#/undo-tree) looks like the closest match to these features. Although, it's hardly a one-to-one match.

It is possible to navigate between changes more readily by visualizing the 'tree' of changes using <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>. It is then possible to navigate to the various changes.

There are no similar 'diffing' or 'timestamping' features available as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

That is the plugin you are searching 
[Emacs-localhistory](https://github.com/cneira/emacs-localhistory)

Comment: Please explain your answer more to make it self-contained.  We prefer not to have link-only answers.